# How to specify directory for PHP script of file which exist in folder inside script current folder?

Tags: php

I have a php script, I need to read a file which is located inside the current script directory. How do I specify the current directory of the executing script?

Comment: Like you do everywhere else: either with `./` or you do not specify it at all.

Answer (score 3):

Not. If you want to get the contents of the file `foo.bar` in the same directory as the script, you can simply call [`file_get_contents("foo.bar")`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

An alternative would be using `./foo.bar`, which will render the same results.

To retreive the current directory, one could call [`getcwd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) or [`basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
file_get_contents("./my_file.txt");

or

file_get_contents("my_file.txt");
```